# How do I apply function to specific columns

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, outliers

I have a sample data frame like the following:

```
well <- c('A1','A2','A3','A4','A5')
area <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,70000,8000)
length <- c(21, 234, 26,70,22)
group<-c('WT','Control','C2','D2','E1')

data <- data.frame(well,area,length,group)
```

And I want to apply the function below to remove rows with outliers from the data frame:

```
Outlier <- function(x){
  low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(mad(x)) 
  high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(mad(x))   
  out <- if_else(x > high, NA,ifelse(x < low, low, x)) 
  out }
```

How do I apply this function to the dataframe excluding certain columns for example column "well" and "group"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack overflow. It might be worth noting that the resulting data frame may provide different results depending on the order of columns upon which outlier exclusion takes place, which doesn't feel robust. Have you looked at packages that might already do this job for you in a robust way?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` in `base R`

```
data[c('area', 'length')] <- lapply(data[c('area', 'length')], Outlier)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
data %>% 
     mutate(across(area:length, Outlier))
#    well  area length   group
#1   A1 21000     21      WT
#2   A2 23400     NA Control
#3   A3 26800     26      C2
#4   A4    NA     NA      D2
#5   A5  8000     22      E1
```

NOTE: Make sure to change the `NA` to `NA_real_` in the 'Outlier' function

```
Outlier <- function(x){
  low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(mad(x)) 
  high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(mad(x))   
  out <- if_else(x > high, NA_real_,ifelse(x < low, low, x)) 
  out }
```

Comment: did not manage to test out lapply function, apparently there is an error with the Outlier function, what could the problem be?

Error: false must be a logical vector, not a double vector.

Comment: @Sure If you had checked my `NOTE`, i specified to change the `NA` to `NA_real_`.  Updated the 'Outlier'

Comment: Thank you, it worked for this data frame. However, when I applied the same code to my original large data frame, this error comes up again " Error: `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector."

Comment: @Sue Can you post a small reproducible example with `dput` for that dataset